Need help to find a generalized solution for a given system
I'm solving two sets of equations, the equations are given below,
$-\frac{t'[\lambda]}{z[\lambda]^{2}}+\frac{z'[\lambda]^2}{z[\lambda]^2}=1$
$t'[\lambda]^2=\frac{p^2 z[\lambda]^{2}z'[\lambda]^2}{1+p^2  z[\lambda]^{2}}$
I'm solving these two equations using DSolve
 DSolve[{-t'[\[Lambda]]^2/z[\[Lambda]]^2  + z'[\[Lambda]]^2/
          z[\[Lambda]]^2 == 1, 
        t'[\[Lambda]]^2 == (
         p^2 z[\[Lambda]]^2 Derivative[1][z][\[Lambda]]^2)/(
         1 + p^2 z[\[Lambda]]^2 )}, {t[\[Lambda]], 
        z[\[Lambda]]}, \[Lambda]] // PowerExpand // Simplify

I'm getting the solution as below,
$z[\lambda]=\pm \frac{\sqrt{-Sech(\lambda\pm c_1)}}{p} $
$t[\lambda]=c_2\pm \frac{Tanh((\lambda\pm c_1)}{p}$
Then, I'm trying to solve a generalized form of the previous equations, and we will get back to the previous sets of equations by putting $\alpha=1$,
$-\frac{t'[\lambda]}{z[\lambda]^{2\alpha}}+\frac{z'[\lambda]^2}{z[\lambda]^2}=1$
$t'[\lambda]^2=\frac{p^2 z[\lambda]^{-2+4\alpha}z'[\lambda]^2}{1+p^2  z[\lambda]^{2\alpha}}$
DSolve[{-t'[\[Lambda]]^2/z[\[Lambda]]^(2 \[Alpha]) + z'[\[Lambda]]^2/
      z[\[Lambda]]^2 == 1, 
    t'[\[Lambda]]^2 == (
     p^2 z[\[Lambda]]^(-2 + 4 \[Alpha])
       Derivative[1][z][\[Lambda]]^2)/(
     1 + p^2 z[\[Lambda]]^(2 \[Alpha]))}, {t[\[Lambda]], 
    z[\[Lambda]]}, \[Lambda]] // PowerExpand // Simplify

Now, these solutions are coming, as shown in the , but errors are also coming, and in the solutions, when I'm putting $\alpha=1$, then this previous solution should appear, but it is not appearing. Can anybody suggest how to remove the errors and get the right solutions?

Works fine in "14.1.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 16, 2024)"

@JieZhu Okay, Thanks.
